# Why do we say: "what time is it?"

Tags: time

Why do we say

> What time is it?

if time is uncountable?  Why don't we say

> What hour is it?

Comment: It's probably short for "What time of **day**  is it?"

Comment: Well, if English were, say, Spanish, I would *have* two meters tall, *have* 20 years in this country, and *have* 48 years old, but that's not idiomatic.

Comment: Cymbeline [Imo: "What hour is it?"](https://books.google.it/books?id=J9pUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=cymbeline+%22what+hour+is+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cymbeline%20%22what%20hour%20is%20it%22&f=false) (1623)

Comment: If I had to translate de French sentence : "Quelle heure est-il ?", I'd say:     "Which hour is it ?" Fortunately we aren't in France.

Comment: In AmE, if someone asked what hour is it and the time was 8:15, people might respond with "8", because that is the hour.  If you were also interested in the minutes, why did you specify only the hour?

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiomatic English usage of ***[time](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=time)*** meaning both extent (of time) and point (in time) that is "hour":

> Abstract sense of "time as an indefinite continuous duration" is recorded from late 14c. Personified since at least 1509 as an aged bald man (but with a forelock) carrying a scythe and an hour-glass. ***In English, a single word encompasses time as "extent" and "point" (French temps/fois, German zeit/mal) as well as "hour" (as in "what time is it?" compare French heure, German Uhr).***

(Etymonline)

Compare also ***[tell time](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tell-time):***

> ***Keep track of the hours; also, know how to read a clock or watch.** For example, This old clock still tells time quite accurately, or He taught his niece to tell time by using a cuckoo clock. This expression uses tell in the sense of “reckon” or “calculate,” a usage dating from about a.d. 1000.

(AHD)